# redirect to different pages based on user role in ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-identity

I'm creating ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application. In that Application
I created Login Page that any user can log, then I'm Trying to redirect user to different pages based on their role.

**ASP.NET Identity** is the membership system here.

In my AspNetRoles Table I have two roles:

```
Id| Name

1 | HEI_Admin

2 | HEI_User
```

This is my Login Controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password); 

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.ConfirmedEmail == true)
                {

                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "HEC_Admin"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "HEC");
                        }
                        //role Admin go to Admin page
                        if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "HEI_User"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "HEI");
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Confirm Email Address.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

but when I try to log using correct credentials I'm getting following error:

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.**

All the connection are double checked, how can achieve this problem.

Comment: This seems to be sql connection error make sure that sql server database is accessible.

Comment: yeah its fine , no errors with that SQL connection , I can Log using Management studio

Comment: Then Check the connection string for identity context.

Comment: that one also check no problem with that one also

Comment: which instance are you using? LocalDB or Sql Server?

Comment: SQL Server , 

my connection string is <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.205;Initial Catalog=HECDB;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=sa;Password=********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Check connection string of your membership database...

Comment: connection string seems fine... did you check if "DefaultConnection" is provided as connection string **name** in your membership provider section inside web.config?

Comment: I figured it out , when I remove 
[Authorize(Roles = "HEC_Admin")]  above the index action in HECController class and when I remove [Authorize(Roles = "HEC_User")]  above the index action in HEIController class this is working fine , 

but then How can give permission ?

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Clerk"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Employee");
                }
                else if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Customer"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
                }
                //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid username or password");
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is the code i used for redirect. also see if the userID and RoleID are inserted into the ASPNETUserRoles table

Comment: Pretty much works for asp.net core 2.0 too, just have to use `var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);` to get user

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any centralized database then Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections.

Go through this [link](http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html) i will solve the same issue with the help of this link